# How to add icon on selected area in High charts map?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, highcharts, rxjs

I am using Highcharts to display maps in my App.

I want to have 2 functionalities:

1) When I click on any area then that area need to be highlighted with red color {done}

2) When I click on any area, then a marker icon to be populated on it {Not done :(}

The following is the code I wrote for click event,

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
      turboThreshold:3000,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      point: {
          events: {
              click: function(e){
                    e.point.series.data[e.point.index].update({
    color: 'red'
  })
              }
          }
      }
  }
 }
```

Here I had  2 bugs:

1) When I click on a state it is getting highlighted but when I select another state the previous color still remains which need to go back to its prev color.

2) Want to have a icon on selected state.

Here Can anyone please help me to fix these 2 issues and I am new to highcharts. Please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating a point you should enable `allowPointSelect` option and set a color in `states.select.color`.

To add some icon on a selected point you can create `mappoint` series with custom marker symbol and update it's data in `select` event function callback from the first series.

```
series: [{
  allowPointSelect: true,
  states: {
    select: {
      color: 'red'
    }
  },
  point: {
    events: {
      select: function() {
        this.series.chart.series[1].setData([{
          x: this._midX,
          y: this._midY
        }]);
      }
    }
  },
  data: data,
  keys: ['code_hasc', 'value'],
  joinBy: 'code_hasc'
}, {
  enableMouseTracking: false,
  colorAxis: false,
  type: 'mappoint',
  marker: {
    symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
  },
  states: {
    inactive: {
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zsp7k50w/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.states.select.color

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.allowPointSelect

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mappoint.marker.symbol